# Also having 'null' result in a query

Tags: mysql

Here are the 3 tables where my data are stored:

**answers**

```
answer_id | question_id | answer
```

**questions**

```
question_id | question
```

**users_answers**

```
user_answer_id | answer_id | question_id
```

What I have to do in practice:

For a given question, collect **all** the answers and count how many people answered A or B for example.
The important point here is that I need all the answers, even if nobody choose it as a possible good answer.

Here is the query I made:

```
SELECT   q.question_id,
         q.question,
         a.answer_id,
         a.answer
FROM     questions AS q
    JOIN answers AS a ON
         q.question_id = a.question_id
    JOIN users_answers ON
         a.answer_id = users_answers.answer_id
WHERE q.question_id = 19
```

Here is my actual result (with example):

```
question_id    |    question    |    answer_id    |    answer

     19             'blabla'             12           'C blabla'
     19             'blabla'             12           'C blabla'
     19             'blabla'             10           'A blabla'
     19             'blabla'             13           'D blabla'
```

No user gave 'B blabla' as a possible good answer, but I still need this result in my results.

How can I do this ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Check out the LEFT JOIN operation

Comment: Your requirements don't make sense to me.  If some answer is _not_ associated with a given question, then how do we even know to include it?  It could be an answer belonging to another question.  Contrary to the upvotes above, I don't think that just switching to a left join will fix this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen may be OP did not specify his question clearly. But it's simple. His DB contains 3 tables: Questions (store questions), Answers (store all available answers for each question: A, B, C, D, ...) and UserAnswer (store answer of a user for a question). Then LEFT JOIN is the go to!

Comment: I disagree, unless there is only one question.

Comment: How is populated your DB?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT questions.question_id, 
       questions.question, 
       answers.answer_id, 
       answers.answer, 
       (SELECT Count(users_answers.user_answer_id) 
        FROM   users_answers 
        WHERE  users_answers.question_id = 1 
               AND users_answers.answer_id IN ( 1, 2 )) AS 
       total_people_answered_anserA_B 
FROM   users_answers 
       INNER JOIN questions 
               ON questions.question_id = users_answers.question_id 
       INNER JOIN answers 
               ON answers.answer_id = users_answers.answer_id 
WHERE  users_answers.question_id = 1;
```